# VMWare initialization error during grails run-app

Tags: grails, vmware

When I type grails run-app to run grails application the cmd gives me this error

```
C:\Users\Mamun\Desktop\web\racetrack>grails run-app   
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:/Program         
Error occurred during initialization of VM           
agent library failed to init: instrument      

C:\Users\Mamun\Desktop\web\racetrack>grails -version
Grails version: 2.0.4
```

But my grails working perfectly.Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this while doing a search of [grails issues](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/5662) on GitHub. Maybe it can help you.